# how to install ubuntu over tiny core

Tags: boot

I have a compaq evo n620c that had windows on it.  I put tiny core on it because I was trying to get something that would let me install ubuntu.  The boot options are
notebook multibay
notebook hard drive
notebook ethernet

I don't remember how I got it to load tiny core, but it won't do anything i want to do.  I tried the mini iso but whether i burn as a file or as contents, it does not boot.  I have plug in net cable but have not been able to make it download.it also does not boot from a memory stick.

Comment: Look up how to PXE boot (ethernet).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the computer meets Ubuntu's minimum spec's? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements Will the computer boot from USB, you might need to use **plop boot manager**. Does the computer have DVD?